# C#.net manipulating timespans and datetimes

Tags: c#, datetime, logic, timespan

I am creating a program that allows an employee to file an overtime.

I have a datepicker named **datePicker1** and four timepickers named: **shiftFrom**, **shiftTo**, **overtimeStart** and **overtimeEnd** and also a dropdown named **otType** (which has 2 options: "before shift" and "after shift").

> The employee will apply for an overtime by selecting a date and
>   entering the time in the timepickers, then selecting the type of
>   overtime (weather if it starts before the shift or after the shift).

**I need to validate if the user inputs are correct.**

I think of adding dates in timepickers values to make it a DateTime then comparing then will do the trick. However I am having trouble in adding Date for **overtimeStart** and **overtimeEnd**.

I did the adding of Date in shiftFrom and shiftTo by doing this

```
TimeSpan shiftfrom, shiftto;
shiftfrom = TimeSpan.Parse(shiftFrom.Text);
shiftto = TimeSpan.Parse(shiftTo.Text);

//variables that will handle the shift hours with date
DateTime dtShiftFrom = new DateTime();
DateTime dtShiftTo = new DateTime();

if(shiftfrom > shiftto)//this means that the employee's shift crosses date
{
    dtShiftFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).Add(shiftfrom);
    dtShiftTo = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).AddDays(1).Add(shiftto);
}
else //the employee's shift from and to falls in the same day
{
    dtShiftFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).Add(shiftfrom);
    dtShiftTo = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).Add(shiftto);
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? And also how can I determine what date falls the **overtimeStart** and **overtimeEnd** if they are placed before the shift or after the shift.

Comment: The proper location for your question is [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) from StackExchange.

Comment: What are the rules for legal overtime? The reason I ask is, why do you have to bother the user specifying if it's overtime *before* or *after*? Surely you should be able to detect that part yourself, with the time values?

Comment: Also, what does a shift with values 08:00 to 08:00 mean? 1 day or 0 hours?

Comment: @AndriyTsok Code Review does not help implement new functionality, but rather reviews existing, working code.

Comment: I just need to validate if the overtime hours is not conflicting to the shift hours

Comment: The part of the question that asks "Is this the best way to do this?" is indeed best suites for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The rest, not so much.

Comment: But what does it mean "not conflicting"? Please give examples. For instance, a shift from 22:00 to 07:00, with overtime from 10:00 to 20:00, is that conflicting or not? And regardless of yes/no, why? And with the same shift, what about 18:00 to 23:00, is that conflicting? Again, why? We need to know the rules for what you consider good/bad and OK data.

Comment: 08:00 to 08:00 is zero hours because they will fall on the same date  base on the date picker

Comment: So there are no shifts that start on one day and end on the next?

Comment: @juharr The code makes it clear that this is possible. A shift from 22:00 to 07:00 will start one day and end the next. (22:00 > 07:00).

Comment: You have 4 variables : OvertimeStart, OverTimeEnd, RegularTimeStart, RegularTimeEnd.  So you have to do following : 1)(OvertimeStart > RegularTimeStart) && (OverTimeStart < RegularTimeEnd).  2) (OverTime End > RegularTimeStart) && (OverTimeEnd < RegularTimeEnd).

Comment: @jdweng Not as simple as that when you take a shift that crosses midnight into account.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But the OP said that "08:00 to 08:00 is zero hours because they will fall on the **same date**"

Comment: But a shift that starts 08:00 and ends 07:59 will not. This is according to the "rules" set forth by the code in the question.

Comment: If you are using a DateTime object my code will always work provided the End times are after the Start times.  A DateTime object starts at Jan 1, 1900 and is a double with the whole number the day count and the fraction   a number where 24 hours = 1.

Comment: @jdweng I agree on that, but this question seems to be about how to interpret time values (without a date) correctly together, so I still think it is pertinent to request clarification from the OP about what he/she means here. I understand what you mean, though most likely overtime means time extra, in which case it is *outside* the shift? and not inside? This is the reason I want to know the rules here. OP says he/she has 4 time pickers, which means no dates, and thus how to interpret/calculate/combine the data. We need more information.

Comment: @jdweng But i only have to use that controls four timepickers a Dropdown and a datepicker

Comment: @CarloLim Please read through my comments and answer them.

Comment: Overtimes are always outside the shift. To make it vslid. Weather it falls before the shift or after

Comment: A shift from 22:00 to 07:00, with overtime values specified as 08:00 to 10:00, is that legal or not?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that is valid because it falls outside the shift. But I need to determine what dates are the 08:00 and 10:00 base on the selected **otType**

Comment: That is quite easy *if you must have the user picking after or before*. If the user selects "after", calculate an interval starting on the same date as the date of the start of the shift, and use the same logic to handle crossing midnight. Then, while the start of the overtime is less than the end of the shift, add one day to the start and end of the overtime. If the user selects *before*, use the date of the end of the shift instead, and reduce the start and end of the overtime by one day instead.

Comment: With the given example, let's say the date is June 5th and the user picked *overtime after shift*. The shift would then go from June 5th 22:00 to June 6th 07:00. Then initially overtime would be 08:00 June 5th to 10:00 June 5th. Then, since this is *before* the shift ends, add one day giving 08:00 June 6th to 10:00 June 6th. Then, since this is after (or equal to) the shift ends, you've found the correct place for the overtime.

Comment: If the user picked *before*, calculate the shift to the same values, but set overtime to be 08:00 June 6th to 10:00 June 6th. Then, since this is *after* the shift starts, move it back one day to 08:00 June 5th to 10:00 June 5th. This is now before (or equal to) the shift starts, so you've found the correct place for the overtime.

Comment: What if the user files an OT before the shift of June 5th 01:00 to June 5th 10:00 and the OT start is June 4th 23:00 to June 5th 00:00

Comment: So, what if? Isn't that OK? You would then start by first calculating the shift datetime values, which would be 01:00 June 5th to 10:00 June 5th. Then you would set overtime to be 23:00 June 5th to 00:00 June 5th (start date of overtime is equal to the date of the end of the shift). Since the end of the overtime is not before or equal to the start of the shift, move overtime back one day to 23:00 June 4th to 00:00 June 5th.

Comment: The problem here is that you've bolded this sentence: **"I need to validate if the user inputs are correct"** However, according to the rules you've laid out so far, *everything* is correct, as long as you move overtime back or forward enough to not be *incorrect*. Again, can you **please** post examples of what would be correct or incorrect?

Comment: You said you wanted to validate that overtime didn't overlap with working time.  The formula I provided does exactly that.  An additional tests that must be performed are follows : 1) End time is after start time. 2) A test that a person doesn't work more that 24 hours in a day.  2) A warning when an operator works less that 8 hours,  3) A test for minimum overtime (some companies require this).